# Why is it possible to use the Inverse Laplace transform to get CDF?

Tags: pr.probability, laplace-transform

I just saw the following on wikipedia about Laplace transformations:

"In probability theory and applied probability, the Laplace transform is defined as an expected value. If $X$ is a random variable with probability density function $f$, then the Laplace transform of $f$ is given by the expectation: $L\lbrace f \rbrace(s) = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{-sX} \right].$

By abuse of notation, this is referred to as the Laplace transform of the random variable $X$ itself.

Of particular use is the ability to recover the cumulative distribution function of a continuous random variable $X$, by means of the Laplace transform as follows:
$F_X(x) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\! \left\{\frac{1}{s}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-sX}\right]\right\}\! (x) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\! \left\{\frac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s)\right\}\! (x)$."

So I understand, how we can use the Inverse Laplace transformation of a random variable $X$ to get the CDF of $X$, but why is this possible? Is there some literature on this? Or even better an easy explanation, which I just don't realize?

Comment: Simply write it as $\mathcal{L}\{F_X\}(x) = \frac{1}{x}\mathcal{L}\{f\}(x)$ and use $F_X'(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: @DieterKadelka thank you for the fast reply, but I am not quite sure, how this helps me. Why can we write $\mathcal{L}\lbrace F_X \rbrace (x)$ as $\frac{1}{x} \mathcal{L}\lbrace F_X \rbrace (x)$? 
If we use the Laplace transformation on the equation mentionend in my question, we are getting your equation, but I would like to understand why the equation in my question holds... 
I apologize for this basic questions, but I'm kinda new to probability theory. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f$ be the density and $F$ the distribution function of $X \geq 0$. Then $F' = f$ (a.s.) and $\mathcal{L}\{F'\}(s) = \mathcal{L}\{f\}(s) = \int_0^\infty f(x) e^{-sx} dx$ and $\mathcal{L}\{F\}(s) = \int_0^\infty F(x) e^{-sx} dx$. Since $F(0) = 0$ and using partial integration we get
$$\int_0^\infty F'(x) e^{-sx} dx = s \int_0^\infty F(x) e^{-sx} dx,$$
i.e. $\frac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}\{f\}(s) = \mathcal{L}\{F\}(s)$. This is equivalent to the assertion.

Comment: Thank you Dieter!! 
This is the explanation I was loking for. 
Greetings Linus